# How does the brain’s limbic system work together to form a working memory, short-term memory, and long-term memory?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, memory

In the past few days, I was reading about the limbic system and how its components (hippocampus, hypothalamus, thalamus, etc.) cooperate.

Among papers and forum posts I read about how those components interact and how each of them plays a vital role in the memory formation.

But, is there someone who can give me an abstract view of how the limbic system components form the cycle that results in the formation of memory?

Something like:

1. The sensory signal comes through the Temporal lobe.
2. Goes to Thalamus where it is classified as new, existing or similar to already existing memory.( maybe somewhere between this or maybe after the next step the working and short-term memory should be involved?)
3. Goes to Hypothalamus to be classified as good or bad experience.
4. Goes to Hippocampus so it can be saved the neocortex at some point (while sleeping for example).

and so on...

Thanks!